# MySQL remove duplicate entries

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I know there are many posts on this, but I couldn't work it out.

I'm working on tidying a library database.
I have this query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(biblionumber SEPARATOR ', ') AS biblionumbers, title, author 
FROM biblio  GROUP BY CONCAT(title,"/",author) 
HAVING COUNT(CONCAT(title,"/",author))>1;
```

It outputs all duplicate sets of entries listing, on each row, the title, author and the duplicate ids (biblionumbers).

I want to write a query which removes all duplicates and keeps only one copy from each, the first id for instance.

Just for the record, the output looks like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  120, 560, 711   |   The history of time    |   John Doe  |
...
```

Is it possible to write such a query?

Comment: i think you want to filter out the duplicates from your result.. SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(biblionumber SEPARATOR ', ') AS biblionumbers, title, author 
FROM biblio

Comment: nope, i want to remove the duplicates completely because the database is accessed by the ILS

Comment: Ok can you post the  show create table statement and some example data?

Comment: show create table statement: http://tny.cz/0dfc12a5

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba183 place inserts (with example data) in the left column and click build schema then you can copy and paste the url here,,,

Comment: and here is some example data: http://www1.datafilehost.com/d/f2691734